# AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager[9] VerifyUserTokenAsync() "code": "InvalidToken",

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, confirmation-email

I am making api in .net 5 and implementing sending email confirmation after succesful registration. This one is killing me and can't see the reason why it returns `Invalid Token`.

So here's my code:

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddAuthentication
...
...
...
services.AddIdentityCore<User>(config =>
{
  config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;

}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<WorkoutDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

**EmailHelper.cs**

```
    public class EmailHelper
    {
        public bool SendEmail(string userEmail, string confirmationLink)
        {
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("noreply@*********.io");
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(userEmail));

            mailMessage.Subject = "Confirm your email";
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;
            mailMessage.Body = confirmationLink;
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("noreply@*********.io", "super secret password");
            client.Host = "host";
            client.Port = 000;
            client.EnableSsl = false;
            client.DeliveryFormat = (SmtpDeliveryFormat)SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            try
            {
                client.Send(mailMessage);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                // log exception
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**AccountService.cs**

```
        public async void RegisterUser(RegisterUserDto dto)
        {
            var uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()[..8];
            var newUser = new User()
            {
                Name = dto.Name,
                LastName = dto.LastName,
                Email = dto.Email,
                EmailConfirmed = false,
                UniqeId = uniqueId,
                RegistrationDate = DateTime.Now,
                Active = false,
                RoleId = dto.RoleId
            };

            var hashedPassword = _passwordHasher.HashPassword(newUser, dto.Password);
            newUser.Password = hashedPassword;
            newUser.NormalizedEmail = dto.Email;
            _context.Add(newUser);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(newUser.Email);
            if(user != null)
            {
                EmailHelper emailHelper = new EmailHelper();
                var token = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(newUser));
                var confirmationLink = "http://localhost:5000/confirmEmail?token=" + token + "&email=" + newUser.NormalizedEmail;
                bool emailResponse = emailHelper.SendEmail(newUser.NormalizedEmail, confirmationLink);
            } 

        }
```

User registration works fine. If email is not registered than registration fails. Otherwise server return 200 as expected. ***Confirmation link is sent*** to email provided during registration process. So till now works as expected.

**EmailController.cs**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IdentityResult> ConfirmEmail([FromQuery]string token, [FromQuery] string email)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
            var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, token);
            if (result.Succeeded) { return IdentityResult.Success; }
            else { return (IdentityResult) result;  }

        }
```

Problem start when clicking on activation link - it throws `warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager[9] VerifyUserTokenAsync() "code": "InvalidToken",`
So activation link is sent, it checks if `user !== null` and than goes to conditional statement and triggers **EmailHelper** which sends link to inbox correctly.

...BUT

When I try to console user - it's empty, nothing shows in console.
Database is updated and user is saved in DB and it's visible and accessible.
In **EmailController.cs** it does not return user

```
   var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
   // if I try to console it it shows nothing - empty(not NULL)
```

If I try to send serialized user data to inbox instead of sending activation link it sends **correct** data from DB.

So to sum up:

- user is created and saved in DB,
- sending user data to inbox instead of confirmationLink sends accurate and correct data of user from database and proves that everything went ok
- confirmation link is generated correctly and send to inbox
- checking `var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(newUser.Email); if(user != null)`  makes user NOT null send allows to send email

And this is killing me and do not know why checking if user exists gives true but trying to access via `await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(newUser.Email);` gives no user(nothing)?
I tried also (in **EmailController**) `_context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.NormalizedEmail == email)` but the result is the same - cannot get user from DB and returns

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager[9]
      VerifyUserTokenAsync() failed with purpose: EmailConfirmation for user.
```

**UPDATE**
IdentityResult output

```
{
  "succeeded": false,
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "InvalidToken",
      "description": "Invalid token."
    }
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE #2**

When I serialize `user` and try to display in console it actually shows correct user data as a string. The problem seems to be that neither
`var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);`
nor  `var user= _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == email);` does not return user that can be verified.

**UPDATE #3**

`No IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider<TUser> named 'xxxx' is registered. System.NotSupportedException: No IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider<TUser> named 'xxxx' is registered.`
But `AddDefaultTokenProviders()` was implemented in Startup.cs
Even tried `config.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider;`
or
`config.Tokens.ProviderMap.Add("Default", new TokenProviderDescriptor(typeof(IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider<User>)));` but the result is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was working on the solution for past few days but finally found a solution!

Since I am using `IdentityUser` but my `User` model did not contain table columns from Identity it cause problem, most likely because that security stamp column was not present.

What I did was to include table columns from `IdentityUser`.

I have also included

```
            services.AddIdentityCore<User>(config =>
            {
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                config.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider; <--- this line!!
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<WorkoutDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Also in **EmailController.cs** in `ConfirmEmail` I had to `decode` token because I was `encoding` this with `HttpUtility.Encode` when egenrating.
 `var tokenDecode = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(token);`

Than I checked with `VerifyUserTokenAsync` which returned `true`.
After that I only received confirmation error when email was clicked that `Username '' is invalid. Username can have only letters and number.`

What I also did was generating `userName` containing only letters and numbers from email that was used for registration and assigning it to `UserName` column in DB set.

After that when email was sent and clicked it returned `IdentityResult.Success`

Damn! It was a long way home. :)

Answer (score 1):

In my .NET core 6, encode send via email:

```
var token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
token = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token));
```

Then you should decode token before confirm:

```
var token  = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(model.Token));
var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, token);
```